# curl --data-urlencode and underscores

Tags: curl, character-encoding, base64

I've been using `curl -XPOST` to post some links to a Telegram channel via a bot api/key, the urls are in form of `https://site/x/pre_encoded_string`, where `pre_encoded_string` is in form (real samples) `XOsmY90GWWA`, `4QHTV_K_WwQ`, and they're generated from perl's `MIME::Base64` `encode_base64url` function.

This fails when the generated string contains the underscore char `_` (as in second sample above), which gets stripped, and `curl` seems to post `4QHTVKWwQ`

Even if I get rid of `--data-*` (binary,raw,urlencode) and pass the string in the url, it gets stripped also.

```
ais@rex ~ # curl -vv -s -XPOST 'https://api.telegram.org/bot1[...]4:AAE[...]Ggd3g/sendMessage?parse_mode=Markdown&chat_id=@xt2RM' --data-urlencode 'text=https://xt2/x/4QHTV_K_WwQ'
*   Trying 149.154.167.198...
* Connected to api.telegram.org (149.154.167.198) port 443 (#0)
* Initializing NSS with certpath: none
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt CApath: none
* NPN, server accepted to use http/1.1
* SSL connection using TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
* Server certificate:
*       subject: CN=api.telegram.org,OU=Domain Control Validated
*       start date: May 23 16:17:38 2015 GMT
*       expire date: May 23 16:17:38 2018 GMT
*       common name: api.telegram.org
*       issuer: CN=Go Daddy Secure Certificate Authority - G2,OU=http://certs.godaddy.com/repository/,O="GoDaddy.com, Inc.",L=Scottsdale,ST=Arizona,C=US
> POST /bot1[...]4:A[...]ApJyf9Pg0/sendMessage?parse_mode=Markdown&chat_id=@xt2RM HTTP/1.1
> Host: api.telegram.org
> User-Agent: curl/7.43.0
> Accept: */*
> Content-Length: 55
> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
> 
* upload completely sent off: 55 out of 55 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Server: nginx/1.9.1
< Date: Mon, 28 Dec 2015 18:55:30 GMT
< Content-Type: application/json
< Content-Length: 193
< Connection: keep-alive
< Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubdomains
< 
* Connection #0 to host api.telegram.org left intact
{"ok":true,"result":{"message_id":1506,"chat":{"id":-1[........]8,"title":"tty2RM","username":"tty2RM","type":"channel"},"date":1451328930,"text":"https:\/\/xt2\/x\/4QHTVKWwQ"}}
ais@rex ~ #
```

Any clue as where my problem is?

Comment: Nice description.  How do you know `curl` is stripping the underscores?  Have you run `curl` with the verbose or trace options?  Can you please post some actual data, command lines, and output? (some of us tend to think in code :-)

Comment: Added -vv output, --trace seemed to be just last line of -vv. Sorry about it.

Comment: Running with `--trace yourtracefile`, in "yourtracefile" it appears that `curl --data-urlencode` does nothing to the underscores and sends them to the server.  Do you know if the server could be stripping the underscores?  The output from the server does not show the underscores.

Comment: I finally got it working by using a temporary file formatted as JSON and using it, but it seems the problem is in telegram's parsemode=Markdown